# Django Oscar Dashboard link not accessible

Tags: django, dashboard, django-oscar

I have developed oscar /django applications before but I am completely stumped by this issue:

I can see the dashboard url in the supported urls list but I am not able to access it.

[404 Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnshD.png)

I have forked a few apps from oscar like voucher, shipping, checkout, reviews and customized them in various ways(None of these are dashboard related)  . This is my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
   'django.contrib.flatpages',
   'oscar.config.Shop',
   'oscar.apps.analytics.apps.AnalyticsConfig',
   'iirns.checkout.apps.CheckoutConfig',
   'oscar.apps.address.apps.AddressConfig',
   'iirns.shipping.apps.ShippingConfig',
   'oscar.apps.catalogue.apps.CatalogueConfig',
   'iirns.catalogue.reviews.apps.CatalogueReviewsConfig',
   'oscar.apps.communication.apps.CommunicationConfig',
   'oscar.apps.partner.apps.PartnerConfig',
   'oscar.apps.basket.apps.BasketConfig',
   'iirns.payment.apps.PaymentConfig',
   'oscar.apps.offer.apps.OfferConfig',
   'oscar.apps.order.apps.OrderConfig',
   'oscar.apps.customer.apps.CustomerConfig',
   'oscar.apps.search.apps.SearchConfig',
   'iirns.voucher.apps.VoucherConfig',
   'oscar.apps.wishlists.apps.WishlistsConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.reports.apps.ReportsDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.users.apps.UsersDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.orders.apps.OrdersDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue.apps.CatalogueDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.offers.apps.OffersDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.partners.apps.PartnersDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.pages.apps.PagesDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.ranges.apps.RangesDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.reviews.apps.ReviewsDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.vouchers.apps.VouchersDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.communications.apps.CommunicationsDashboardConfig',
   'oscar.apps.dashboard.shipping.apps.ShippingDashboardConfig',

   # 3rd-party apps that oscar depends on
   'widget_tweaks',
   'haystack',
   'treebeard',
   'sorl.thumbnail',
   'django_tables2',

   'mailer',
   'extra',
]
```

and this is my root url file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.apps import apps
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('extra.urls')),
    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: The path you are visiting (`/iirns/dashboard/`) does not match the URL in your patterns (`/dashboard/`)... if you want the Oscar URLs to be inside the `iirns/` prefix then you need to include that in the path for the URL pattern that includes the Oscar URLs.

Comment: Ah yes! I see it now. I had deployed the app on apache2 on the iirns path. I removed the iirns and now its working. This never happens with django. Maybe oscar expects all urls to be on the root path?

Comment: Oscar doesn't do anything out of the ordinary - it runs on whatever URL path you have specified in your URL config.